# Representation of $C^{*} (S_{\infty})$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, kk-theory

I was wondering what is the group $C^{*}$-algebra of infinite symmetric group?

Mainly, I was trying to calculate the k-theory of $C^{*}$-algebra of infinite symmetric group and I found [K-Theory of $C^{*}(X)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370397/k-theory-of-cx) .

But the Vershik's paper is kind of difficult to understand. Is there a simpler way or an alternative way?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: I think the best starting point would be to understand the representation theory of the symmetric groups and what this has to do with symmetric functions.

Comment: Any particular reference?

Comment: "Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials" by Ian Grant Macdonald is a good reference for symmetric functions and has a chapter on characters of the symmetric groups.